# How to apply Ipv4NetworkConfigurator and UnitDiskRadioMedium of the network on dynamic module in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++, inet

I have a mobile sensor network, I need to simulate a clone attack on the network, so I create dynamically a node at runtime. The node is created successfully but it does not have all properties as other nodes, No IPAddress, so it does not communicate with other nodes. And it is not mobile while I specify mobility parameters in .ini file. Here is my code :

```
network Drones
{
    parameters:
        int numHosts;

    submodules:
        visualizer: IntegratedVisualizer {
            @display("p=100,100");
        }

        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            parameters:
                config = xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='145.236.x.x' netmask='255.255.0.0'/></config>");
                @display("p=100,300");
        }

        radioMedium: UnitDiskRadioMedium{
            @display("p=100,500");
        }

        host[numHosts]: WirelessHost {
            @display("i=misc/node_vs");
        }

        clone: WirelessHost {
            @dynamic;
            @display("i=misc/node_vs");

        }
}

cModuleType *moduleType = cModuleType::get("inet.node.inet.WirelessHost");
cModule* module = moduleType->create("clone", this);
module->finalizeParameters();
module->buildInside();
module->scheduleStart(simTime() + updateInterval);


*.clone.osgModel = "3d/drone.ive.100.scale.0,0,90.rot"

*.clone.mobility.typename = "MassMobility"
*.clone.mobility.changeInterval = 1s
*.clone.mobility.initialMovementHeading = uniform(0deg, 360deg)
*.clone.mobility.initialMovementElevation = uniform(-90deg, 90deg)
*.clone.mobility.angleDelta = uniform(-10deg,10deg)
*.clone.mobility.rotationAxisAngle = uniform(-10deg,10deg)
*.clone.mobility.speed = uniform(10mps,20mps)
*.clone.mobility.faceForward = false

*.clone.numApps = 1
*.clone.app[0].typename = "myApp"
*.clone.app[0].destPort = 5000
*.clone.app[0].sendInterval = exponential(12ms)
```

I expect a mobile node which receives and sends packets, but the actual output shows a static node with no address and which does not communicate with other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You should also do a callInitialize() in the module. The automatic static configuration will not work for dynamic modules though.

Comment: I add the instruction : module->callInitialize() but unfortunately, I got the visualizer issue another time.